# Retornar a mensagem de firebase.auth no typescript

Tags: firebase, typescript

Eu estou usando Firebase no back end desse login, mas não to conseguindo usar as informações que voltam do firebase.auth para checar se deu erro ou não e assim setar o autenticacao false ou true, o msgErro vira um objeto json, que eu consigo usar no html usando o pipe | json que mostra a mensagem que eu to retornado dentro da funcao de erro.

Alguém sabe como eu faço para acessar esse objeto e retirar a informação que eu preciso?

```js
private usuario : Usuario = new Usuario();
private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
private verificarSenha: string;
private msgErro : any;
private autenticacao : boolean = true;

registrar(){
        if (this.verificarSenha == this.usuario.senha){
            this.register();
            //this.msgErro ? this.autenticacao = false : this.autenticacao = true;
        }
        else {
            this.msgErro = 'auth/wrong-password'
            this.autenticacao = false;
        }
    }

    register(){
        this.msgErro = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.usuario.login, this.usuario.senha).catch(function(err : firebase.FirebaseError) {
            if (err.code){
                 if (err.code === 'auth/weak-password') {
                    return "A senha deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres";
                }
                else if(err.code === 'auth/invalid-email'){
                    return "O email informado é invalido";
                }
                else {
                    return "O email informado ja está cadastrado";
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form" [class.erro]="!autenticacao" >
        <div style="color: #4CAF50; margin-bottom : 20px">
            <h4>BEM VINDO AO UM HELP</h4>
            <p class="message">Por favor, insira o email e a senha que deseja usar</p>
        </div>
        <form class="login-form has-danger">
            <input [(ngModel)]="usuario.login" name="login" type="text" c placeholder="Usuario"/>
            <input [(ngModel)]="usuario.senha" name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Senha"/>
            <input [(ngModel)]="verificarSenha" name="verificar" type="password" placeholder="Repita a senha"/>
            <div class="form-control-feedback has-danger"> {{ msgErro.ya | json }} </div>
            <div *ngIf="msgErro == 'auth/wrong-password'" class="form-control-feedback has-danger">As senhas informadas não correspondem</div>
            <button (click)="registrar()">Registrar</button>
            <button>Google</button>
            <button>Facebook</button>
            <button>voltar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro problema

A mensagem de erro não será retorna pela função createUserWithEmailAndPassword
mas sim no callback (função anônima criada para tratar o erro)

Segundo, a variável msgErro não vai estar acessível através do this e por isso  deve ser criada uma variável no outro nome (_this por exemplo) para atribuir o objeto pai

a solução é esta

```
register() {
      let _this = this;

               firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.usuario.login, this.usuario.senha).catch(function(err : firebase.FirebaseError) {
                    if (err.code){
                         if (err.code === 'auth/weak-password') {
                            _this.msgErro = "A senha deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres";
                        }
                        else if(err.code === 'auth/invalid-email'){
                           _this.msgErro = "O email informado é invalido";
                        }
                        else {
                            _this.msgErro = "O email informado ja está cadastrado";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```